# Error running rails s on M1 chip (Apple Silicon)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I'm trying to learn Rails and experiencing an issue when I try to run my server. I've read posts from reddit, Youtube tutorials, Stackover flow posts and blog, concluded that there's really known issues when you're using M1 chip for development purposes (excluding front-end).

Based on the forum thread link I've stated below, the msgpack isn't compatible with Apple architecture. I really don't have any idea how to build it which will make it compatible with M1 chip.

**PS:** I'm relatively new in Rails, if there's anything wrong with my post, I apologize in advance. I'm open to corrections.

**Expected output:**

Run rails s on M1 chip (without using rosetta, if possible)

**What I've done so far:**

1. Tried bundle install (see below for the output after bundle install)
2. quit terminal after bundle install
3. Read through this forum thread
   https://superuser.com/questions/1618896/how-to-run-ruby-on-rails-on-new-macbook-air-m1/1619366

**My setup:**

ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [arm64-darwin20] (System ruby)

Rails 6.1.1

yarn 1.22.10

node v14.15.4

Version manager: ASDF

IDE: Sublime Text

**Bundle install output:**

```
Using rake 13.0.3
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
Using i18n 1.8.8
Using minitest 5.14.3
Using tzinfo 2.0.4
Using zeitwerk 2.4.2
Using activesupport 6.1.1
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubi 1.10.0
Using racc 1.5.2
Using nokogiri 1.11.1 (arm64-darwin)
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.9.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Using actionview 6.1.1
Using rack 2.2.3
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using actionpack 6.1.1
Using nio4r 2.5.4
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Using websocket-driver 0.7.3
Using actioncable 6.1.1
Using globalid 0.4.2
Using activejob 6.1.1
Using activemodel 6.1.1
Using activerecord 6.1.1
Using mimemagic 0.3.5
Using marcel 0.3.3
Using activestorage 6.1.1
Using mini_mime 1.0.2
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailbox 6.1.1
Using actionmailer 6.1.1
Using actiontext 6.1.1
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using addressable 2.7.0
Using bindex 0.8.1
Using msgpack 1.4.2
Using bootsnap 1.7.0
Using bundler 2.2.7
Using byebug 11.1.3
Using regexp_parser 2.0.3
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using capybara 3.35.3
Using childprocess 3.0.0
Using ffi 1.14.2
Using jbuilder 2.11.2
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.4
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Using listen 3.4.1
Using method_source 1.0.0
Using puma 5.2.0
Using rack-mini-profiler 2.3.1
Using rack-proxy 0.6.5
Using thor 1.1.0
Using railties 6.1.1
Using sprockets 4.0.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.2
Using rails 6.1.1
Using rubyzip 2.3.0
Using sassc 2.4.0
Using tilt 2.0.10
Using sassc-rails 2.1.2
Using sass-rails 6.0.0
Using selenium-webdriver 3.142.7
Using semantic_range 2.3.1
Using spring 2.1.1
Using sqlite3 1.4.2
Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Using turbolinks 5.2.1
Using web-console 4.1.0
Using webdrivers 4.5.0
Using webpacker 5.2.1
Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 74 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

**Output of rails s:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    29: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
    28: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
    27: from /Users/leatinoso/facebook/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    26: from /Users/leatinoso/facebook/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
    25: from /Users/leatinoso/facebook/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    24: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    23: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    22: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    21: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    20: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    18: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    17: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    16: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    15: from /Users/leatinoso/facebook/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /Users/leatinoso/facebook/bin/rails:4:in `require_relative'
    13: from /Users/leatinoso/facebook/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /Users/leatinoso/facebook/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    11: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `require_relative'
     9: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `require_relative'
     7: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:61:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:61:in `require_relative'
     5: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:41:in `with_gems'
     3: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
     2: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `require'
     1: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `require': dlopen(/Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find: (LoadError)
    /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture - /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle
    30: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
    29: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
    28: from /Users/leatinoso/facebook/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    27: from /Users/leatinoso/facebook/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
    26: from /Users/leatinoso/facebook/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    25: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    24: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    23: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    21: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    19: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    18: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    17: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    16: from /Users/leatinoso/facebook/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users/leatinoso/facebook/bin/rails:4:in `require_relative'
    14: from /Users/leatinoso/facebook/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /Users/leatinoso/facebook/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    12: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    10: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `require_relative'
     8: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:61:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:61:in `require_relative'
     6: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:40:in `with_gems'
     4: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:44:in `rescue in with_gems'
     3: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
     2: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `require'
     1: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `require': dlopen(/Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find: (LoadError)
    /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture - /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle
```

**Gemfile.lock file:**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.1.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.1.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.1)
      activejob (= 6.1.1)
      activerecord (= 6.1.1)
      activestorage (= 6.1.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.1)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.1.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.1)
      actionview (= 6.1.1)
      activejob (= 6.1.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.1.1)
      actionview (= 6.1.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.1)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.9)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.1.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.1)
      activerecord (= 6.1.1)
      activestorage (= 6.1.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.1.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.1.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.1.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.1)
    activerecord (6.1.1)
      activemodel (= 6.1.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.1)
    activestorage (6.1.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.1)
      activejob (= 6.1.1)
      activerecord (= 6.1.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.1)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    activesupport (6.1.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.7.0)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capybara (3.35.3)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.8)
    crass (1.0.6)
    erubi (1.10.0)
    ffi (1.14.2)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.8.8)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.11.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    listen (3.4.1)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    loofah (2.9.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mimemagic (0.3.5)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    minitest (5.14.3)
    msgpack (1.4.2)
    nio4r (2.5.4)
    nokogiri (1.11.1-arm64-darwin)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    puma (5.2.0)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.5.2)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-mini-profiler (2.3.1)
      rack (>= 1.2.0)
    rack-proxy (0.6.5)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.1.1)
      actioncable (= 6.1.1)
      actionmailbox (= 6.1.1)
      actionmailer (= 6.1.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.1)
      actiontext (= 6.1.1)
      actionview (= 6.1.1)
      activejob (= 6.1.1)
      activemodel (= 6.1.1)
      activerecord (= 6.1.1)
      activestorage (= 6.1.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.1)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 6.1.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (6.1.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (~> 1.0)
    rake (13.0.3)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.4)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (2.0.3)
    rubyzip (2.3.0)
    sass-rails (6.0.0)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    sassc (2.4.0)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    semantic_range (2.3.1)
    spring (2.1.1)
    sprockets (4.0.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.4.2)
    thor (1.1.0)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    web-console (4.1.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (4.5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    webpacker (5.2.1)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 5.2)
      semantic_range (>= 2.3.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.3)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.4.2)

PLATFORMS
  arm64-darwin-20

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (>= 1.4.4)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 3.26)
  jbuilder (~> 2.7)
  listen (~> 3.3)
  puma (~> 5.0)
  rack-mini-profiler (~> 2.0)
  rails (~> 6.1.1)
  sass-rails (>= 6)
  selenium-webdriver
  spring
  sqlite3 (~> 1.4)
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  web-console (>= 4.1.0)
  webdrivers
  webpacker (~> 5.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.7.2p137

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.7
```

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**UPDATE**
installing the msgpack gem did the trick. Thank you for all your inputs though. I simply run the command "gem i msgpack" through terminal.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-ruby/issues/195

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your terminal

```
$ gem install msgpack
```

Answer (score 7):

I am also a MBA M1 rails developer. After running into some issues with specific gems (`nokogiri` and `ffi` among others) i decided to uninstall everything and start from scratch making a `terminal - rosetta` shortcut in my applications. I redid the installation of everything from `homebrew` to `asdf` and `rails` through that and have been happily developing ever since.

A very nice guide can be found [here](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/a-rubyist-s-apple-m1-review). I believe i followed that up to the **UPDATE** point where he goes for the native version if you want to try that out. Note if you follow that guilde through your `terminal-rosetta` you don't need to make the **aliases** `a`, `ibrew` or run them where it is specified.

I have to say working over a month in this setup, it's been rock solid and the only thing i **occasionally** have to do is update some specific gems that cause trouble on older projects.

Let me know how it works out for you if you go for either the Rosetta or Native version.